# Begin rescue retry error

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement

If this code executes the `else` statement, I want it to retry either from `rescue` or from `begin`.
Running the code asks me for an input and, when I input it, the code doesn't work.

1- What can I do to make this code work with the else statement running the `retry`?

2- Why does removing `rescue` create a `retry Syntax Error`?

```
# Creates input method
def input
  x = gets.to_i
end

#Begins the first choice
begin

  puts "What will you do?
  1- Get a closer look
  2- Go in the opposite direction
  Write your input an press enter:"
rescue
  #Calls input method
  choice = input
  if choice == 1
    puts "You get a closer look and..."
  elsif choice == 2
    puts "You go in the opposite direction, out of trouble"
  else 
    puts "Incorrect input, enter a number between the one's avaliables:"
  end

  #Retries if the choice is error
retry if choice != 1||2
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a *rescue block* is for handling exceptions, I really don't think it's needed here. A loop will do the job.

```
puts "What will you do?",
     "1- Get a closer look",
     "2- Go in the opposite direction",
     "Write your input and press enter:"

loop do
  choice = gets.to_i
  if choice == 1
    puts "You get a closer look and..."
    break
  elsif choice == 2
    puts "You go in the opposite direction, out of trouble"
    break
  else
    puts "Incorrect input, enter a number between the ones available:"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for. :)